# Does this sentence conveys the message of awareness of coronavirus and being alert?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, sentence-meaning

In India, the lockdown is kind of ended. It's still there but most of the things are allowed but precautions. That doesn't mean coronavirus cases are decreasing in India.

Basically, I want to say that it's not over. We must still be alert, and follow rules and regulations and don't become careless by doing unnecessary things like roaming on roads, malls etc. unless very necessary.

Here's the sentence:

It's time to be defensive, not aggressive. I've used these words from Cricket, to relate it with cricket.

(In cricket, when you're defensive, there are less chances of you getting out, but when you're aggressive, there are more chances that you might get out)

So does it convey the mentioned thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It does convey the mentioned thing**, but...

It is perhaps better to **make cricket allusion clearer** as not many people will understand it. Simply because not many people play the game on a regular basis/played it in the past/are familiar with it. A regular person reading the sentence would probably be left with a reaction like: *"What? What did you mean?"*

So, I would like to suggest something along the lines of

> (1) *It is time to be defensive - as cricket players do to lower their chances of getting out of the game - rather than aggressive.*

So that the sentence is easier to understand for one who's reading it.

P.S. Also, if we want to make the emphasis **as obvious as possible**, we can add something like *"it is not time to forget all the precautions, but..."* For example:

> (2) *It is not the time to forget all the precautions and play aggressively: it is rather the time to play defensively, as cricket players do to lower their chances of getting out of the game.*

This way, the sentence absolutely conveys the mentioned thing. **But if you have already explained everything** before introducing this cricket-sentence, **then you can stop on a version (1).** No one forbids using metaphors in writing or speech, and we used a metaphor here.

Comment: Actually I will add a sutiable image to explain the cricket part. That won't be a problem.

Comment: Secondly, "than agressive" or "rather than agressive"?

Comment: It is mostly a matter of emphasis. **Rather than** ([CALD definitions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rather?q=rather+than)) can mean _"more accurately; more exactly"_, can show _preference_ in one thing over another, can add more _colour_, so to say, into the writing, can be used in expressing an opposite opinion, but *"than aggressive"* and *"rather than aggressive"* have the same meaning, basically. Expression means the same despite which version you use.

Comment: Okay, but doesn't it seem odd *It is time to be defensive than aggressive* as compared to *It is time to be defensive not aggressive*?

Comment: It seems odd because a comma needs to be put in there: _It is time to be defensive, not aggressive_

Comment: You say _It is perhaps better to make cricket allusion clearer as not many people will understand it_ but the OP is talking about India and is, presumably, writing for an Indian audience. In India cricket is a near-universal obsession as I understand it. In the Indian context cricket analogies will be as widely understood as baseball, gridiron football and ice hockey analogies are in the US. The same applies to Pakistan, Bangladesh, Australia, New Zealand and South Africa although perhaps slightly less in the UK. For an Indian audience all I would do is say "it's time to _play defensively_".